# Custom ticks/Scale in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

How can I create custom ticks that will print power of 10 in d3js?

eg:0____10_______100________1000_________________10000_______________________100000

I tried with tickValues but it will fail when we pan or zoom out the graph.

Comment: i suppose [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues) didn't work, right?

Comment: this method doesn't work when we pan or zoom out the graph. when we pan it will show fixed amount of ticks. I think handling display value manually is really pain when the graph supports all graph operations. Is there any way to handle this kind of scale?